# ggplot2 does not plot multiple groups of a variable, only plots one line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot with multiple lines corresponding to different groups of variable "Prob" (0.1, 0.5 and 0.9) using ggplot. Although that, when I run the code, it only plots one line instead of 3. Thanks for the help :)

Here my code:

```
Prob <- c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9)

nit <- c(0.9,0.902777775,0.90555555,0.908333325,0.9111111,0.913888875,0.91666665,0.919444425,0.9222222,0.924999975,0.92777775,0.930555525,0.9333333,0.936111075,0.93888885,0.941666625,0.9444444,0.947222175,0.94999995,0.952777725,0.9555555,0.958333275,0.96111105,0.963888825,0.9666666,0.969444375,0.97222215,0.974999925,0.9777777,0.980555475,0.98333325,0.986111025,0.9888888,0.991666575,0.99444435,0.997222125,0.9999999,0.9,0.902777775,0.90555555,0.908333325,0.9111111,0.913888875,0.91666665,0.919444425,0.9222222,0.924999975,0.92777775,0.930555525,0.9333333,0.936111075,0.93888885,0.941666625,0.9444444,0.947222175,0.94999995,0.952777725,0.9555555,0.958333275,0.96111105,0.963888825,0.9666666,0.969444375,0.97222215,0.974999925,0.9777777,0.980555475,0.98333325,0.986111025,0.9888888,0.991666575,0.99444435,0.997222125,0.9999999,0.9,0.902777775,0.90555555,0.908333325,0.9111111,0.913888875,0.91666665,0.919444425,0.9222222,0.924999975,0.92777775,0.930555525,0.9333333,0.936111075,0.93888885,0.941666625,0.9444444,0.947222175,0.94999995,0.952777725,0.9555555,0.958333275,0.96111105,0.963888825,0.9666666,0.969444375,0.97222215,0.974999925,0.9777777,0.980555475,0.98333325,0.986111025,0.9888888,0.991666575,0.99444435,0.997222125,0.9999999)

greek <- log((1-Prob)/Prob)/-10
italian <- ((0.997-nit)/(0.997-0.97))^3 
Temp<-c(rep(25,111))
GT <- ((30-Temp)/(30-3.3))^3
GH <- 1-GT-italian
acid <- (-1*(((sign(GH)*(abs(GH)^(1/3)))*(7-5))-7))
Species<-c(rep("Case",111))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Prob,greek,GT,GH,italian, Temp,acid,nit, Species))
ggplot()  +
        geom_line(data = data, aes_string(x = acid, y = nit, group = Prob, color = factor(Prob)), size = 0.8)
```

Comment: The data is on the same x,y positions, so they are overplotted. Following your code, that makes sense because `Prop` is only used in the calculation of `greek` and doesn't flow into `nit` or `acid` in a way I can detect.

Comment: @teunbrand the problem is that ggplot plot the groups of the Prob variable when variables (Prob, nit, greek,italian,Temp,GT,GH,acid,Species) are taken from an Excel file, but not, when I calculate them using the R code described above.. I don't know the error... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be kind of two parts:

1. In your data frame `data`, the columns that should be numeric are not numeric.
2. The reason why you only see one line.

#### Fixing the Data Frame and Using `aes()` in place of `aes_string()`

I noticed something was odd when you had `as.data.frame(cbind(...` to make your data frame and are using `aes_string(..` within the `ggplot` portion.  If you do a quick check on `data` via `str(data)`, you'll see all of your columns in `data` are characters, whereas in the environment the data prepared in the code for their respective columns are numeric.  Ex. `acid` is numeric, yet `data$acid` is a character.

The reason for this is that you're binding the columns into a data frame by using `as.data.frame(cbind(...`.  This results in all data being coerced into a character, so you loose the numeric nature of the data.  This is also why you have to use `aes_string(...)` to make it work instead of `aes()`.  To bind vectors together into a data frame, use `data.frame(...`, not `as.data.frame(cbind(...`.

To fix all this, bind your columns together like this + the `ggplot` code:

```
data <- data.frame(Prob,greek,GT,GH,italian, Temp,acid,nit, Species)
# data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Prob,greek,GT,GH,italian, Temp,acid,nit, Species))

ggplot()  +
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x = acid, y = nit, group = Prob, color = factor(Prob)), size = 0.8)
```

[image]

#### Why is there only one line?

The simple answer to why you only see one line is that the line for each of the values of `data$Prob` is equal.  What you see is the effect of *overplotting*.  It means that the line for `data$Prob == 0.1` is the same line when `data$Prob == 0.5` and `data$Prob = 0.9`.

To demonstrate this, let's separate each.  I'm going to do this realizing that `Prob` could be created by repeating 0.1, 0.5, and 0.9 each 37 times in a row.  I'll create a factor that I'll use as multiplication factor for `data$nit` that will result in separating our our lines:

```
my_factor <- rep(c(1,1.1,1.5), each=37)  # our multiplication fractor
data$nit <- data$nit * my_factor   # new nit column

# same plot code
ggplot()  +
      geom_line(data=data, aes(x = acid, y = nit, group = Prob, color = factor(Prob)), size = 0.8)
```

[image]

There ya go.  We have all lines there, you just could not see them due to overplotting.  You can convince yourself of this without the multiplication business and the original data by comparing the plots for each `data$Prob`:

```
# use original dataset as above
ggplot()  +
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x = acid, y = nit, group = Prob, color = factor(Prob)), size = 0.8) +
  facet_wrap(~Prob)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your response @chemdork123 but its not the problem.. I realize that the three lines should be different and they don't overlap..If the variable "acid" is replaced by a vector of numbers instead of a formula, the ggplot works. So I think that the error is related with that with the formula to calculate "acid" comprising a cubic square root, R isn't able to recognize it as a numeric vector (although I checked and its class is numeric). I don't know hoe to solve this problem....Thanks for the help again :)

Comment: If you think the issue is with the calculation of the cube root - it's not a `ggplot` issue, then.  Although - still very much better idea to use `data.fram(...` instead of `as.data.frame(cbind(...`, unless you want to spend all time converting back to the right class.  As for cube root, there is a `cuberoot()` function in the `kader` package ([documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kader/versions/0.0.8/topics/cuberoot)).